# Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter - Code 10

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

**System Specs:**

I'm currently running a Dell laptop m3800 with the Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 adapter, 16 GB of RAM and Windows 8.1. Within this laptop, I'm running a Server 2008 R2 Standard instance via Hyper-V with a dedicated 8 GB of RAM, SharePoint 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

**Problem:**

I've had this configuration for some time now (about 4.5 - 5 months). I use the Hyper-V instance for SharePoint development. While Hyper-V hasn't always liked the network adapter, I've had it working for the entire time that I've had the laptop. The virtual switch that I configured is set to:

```
External Network
- Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
- Allow management operating system to share this network adapter [ CHECKED ]
```

Before I left for Christmas break, I shutdown the VM and created a checkpoint with everything running smoothly. Upon returning, I found this morning that the VM has no internet connection. I checked Device Manager within the Server 2008 R2 VM and found that *Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter* has a yellow exclaimation point. In the properties window, the following message displays:

```
This device cannot start. (Code 10)
```

**Solutions I've Tried:**

I've tried both, reverting back to my Pre-Christmas Checkpoint and running the Network Troubleshooting Wizard. The Wizard told me that the adapter was indeed having trouble communicating with the hardware but that it could not fix the issue. Neither operation successfully fixed the issue.

In addition, I've also tried Google Searching for the issue:

- [Search 1: Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter this device cannot start](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=microsoft%20virtual%20machine%20bus%20network%20adapter%20this%20device%20cannot%20start)
- [Search 2: Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter this device cannot start code 10](https://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft+virtual+machine+bus+network+adapter+this+device+cannot+start+code+10&oq=micros&aqs=chrome.2.69i60j69i59l2j0j69i65j69i57.1824j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)
- [Search 3: Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter code 10](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=microsoft%20virtual%20machine%20bus%20network%20adapter%20code%2010)
- [Search 4: code 10 Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ie=UTF-8&q=code%2010%20microsoft%20virtual%20machine%20bus%20network%20adapter)

These have all been tried with no avail. I found somewhere in these links that Virtual Machine Queuing (VMQ) may have been a problem. I tried disabling and re-enabling with no luck.

Finally, I tried recreating the Virtual Switch all together in Hyper-V Manager. Unfortunately, still no luck.

**Question:**

Unfortunately, I've exhausted the extent of my knowledge with respect to networking and Hyper-V so now it's time to turn to the experts at Super User. Does anyone have any ideas:

- What changed that may be causing this error?
- Any possible solutions to try and fix this error?

As a side note, I did use this machine on my home network over Christmas break. Hyper-V was shut down during this time. I also checked my Windows Updates to see if there was a possible conflict. The only updates that installed over Christmas break were Microsoft Endpoint Protection Definition Updates.